# Calculated field in Google Data Studio that gets current user email

Tags: google-apps-script, looker-studio

I would like to get the email address of the current viewer of a google data studio dashboard and use it as a Dimension in every chart so that the user will only be able to view data that is relevant to him/her. Is that possible in Data studio?

Comment: It is possible with some data sources like BigQuery. What are you using?

Comment: We're looking into options right now. We initially thought of utilizing our current host with mysql but bigquery looks interesting. Can you give me more information on how to do it in bigquery?

Answer (score 1):

It's not straightforward but it's possible using views (see link) in BigQuery and then using Viewer's Credentials in Data Studio when creating the data source (Owners Credentials are selected by default)

[Row-level permissions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/views#row-level-permissions)